# Index fund that tracks gold and other commodities

Tags: canada, index-fund, gold, commodities, precious-metals

Is there an index fund that tracks the index for precious metals? How about a fund that tracks an index just for gold?(I guess this is not possible)
And is there a fund that tracks overall commodities index?
Answers specific to the Canadian investors are most welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know answers that would be specific to Canada but one of the main ETF funds that tracks gold prices is [GLD (SPDR Gold Trust)](http://www.google.com/finance?client=ob&q=NYSE%3aGLD) another is [IAU (iShares Gold Trust)](http://www.google.com/finance?client=ob&q=NYSE%3aIAU).

Also, there are several ETF's that combine different precious metals together and can be traded. You can find a [fairly decent list](http://etf.stock-encyclopedia.com/category/precious-metals-etfs.html) here on the Stock Encylopedia site.

Comment: IAU is the iShare ETF, lower fees, interesting that GLD is the most popular, maybe better ad agency?

Comment: "The investment objective of the Trust is for the Shares to reflect the performance of the price of gold bullion." - So this is not actually investing in gold?  If it is then why would it not reflect the price of Gold?

Comment: @Chad, To make the shares affordable, it's likely that each share represents less than one ounce of gold. I believe that IAU is basically 1/100th oz. per share and GLD is 1/10 oz  (in both cases, as of when the fund started, and reduced very slightly due to expenses). Read more carefully and you will see each fund does in fact hold gold, buying and selling as needed as people buy into or out of the funds.

Comment: @Chuck - Is it buying physical gold or contracts?

Comment: @Joe Taxpayer, GLD is slightly older, maybe it just got a head start?  That or there is a psychological effect of it's higher price per share? Maybe due to 10x lower fee's for anyone paying a per share commission when trading it? or a better ticker symbol? (after all what non chemistry geeks remember AU is the chemical symbol for gold?) Hard to know, but I'd agree that the slightly lower expenses would make IAU the better choice if you are trading on a flat rate per trade basis.

Comment: GLD summary from Yahoo finance: "The investment seeks to replicate the performance, net of expenses, of the price of gold bullion. **The trust holds gold, and is expected to issue baskets in exchange for deposits of gold, and to distribute gold in connection with redemption of baskets"**. The gold held by the trust will only be sold on an as-needed basis to pay trust expenses, in the event the trust terminates and liquidates its assets, or as otherwise required by law or regulation.."  The ext for IAU is similar: **It receives gold deposited with it in exchange for the creation of baskets.."**

Answer (score 3):

Barclays offers an iPath ETN (not quite an ETF), [DJP](http://etf.stock-encyclopedia.com/DJP.html), which tracks the total return of the Dow Jones-AIG Commodity Index.